# why am i getting an error here

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, ether, smart-contract-wallets

[image]

I recently ran into an issue launching my token but I have no idea
why its giving me an error. ive went through it numerous of times

Comment: Please post your entire code, chances are the compiler isn't pinning the error down to the correct line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.